# Mapping a large List of Entities to a PagedList of ViewModels

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, pagedlist

How to use PagedList in a web application based on ASP MVC in combination with ViewModels.

I want to make a PagedList of Viewmodels, so first I have to map the Entities to Viewmodels.

When I fetch a large list, it it very slow because first the mapping is executed before the PagedList is made (so the whole List of Entities is fetched).

What is the best way to solve this issue?

```
IEnumerable<InvoiceData> invoiceData = dataService.GetInvoiceData(locationId);

Mapper.CreateMap<InvoiceData, ViewModelInvoiceData>();
IEnumerable<ViewModelInvoiceData> vmInvoiceData = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<InvoiceData>, IEnumerable<ViewModelInvoiceData>>(invoiceData);

IPagedList<InvoiceDataViewModel> pagedListVMInvoiceData = vmInvoiceData.ToPagedList(page, pageSize);
```

(I also use a mapping framework, but it's of course the same problem with a custom mapper class)

Comment: Did you try to use IQueryable instead ? Is it supported by your dataService ? Using Iqueryable would allow the IPagedList to deffer the query into the database thus limiting the number of object mapped to only what's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Why you didn't page your data on server? And after that create manual pager like in example 2 from [troygoode  / PagedList](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList) ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I sped up my results (they are still not that fast, but faster) by using the IQueryable interface instead of the IEnumerable

Change this:

```
IEnumerable<InvoiceData> invoiceData = dataService.GetInvoiceData(locationId);
```

To this:

```
IQueryable<InvoiceData> invoiceData = dataService.GetInvoiceData(locationId);
```